# Undefined reference to `PageSetupDlgW@4' when linking in Qt

Tags: qt, winapi

I tried to use Windows api PageSetupDlg in Qt to save some time. However, I get errors during compilation in the title. Here is my code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PAGESETUPDLG lppsd;
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
//#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
//    MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("This is windows window"),
//               TEXT("HAHAYOYO"),MB_OK);
    PageSetupDlg(&lppsd);
//#endif
    return a.exec();
}
```

I 've added the `LIBS += -LC:\Windows\System32\ComDlg32.dll` in the .pro file, however it doesn't work. I'm not sure whether it is correct to write like that.

My second question is that do I need to add the `#ifdef` & `#endif` statements when I try to call a Windows API function? Since the `MessageBox` function runs correctly without them.

Comment: I hope you make it abundantly clear in your documentation for this project that although you're using Qt, you've also used platform restricting libraries, therefore negating any benefit you could have achieved by using Qt. If you read between the lines **I think this is a bad idea**.

Comment: @Styne666 Ok,I know it's not good to do so.I'm writing this as an example to get familiar with winapi.Does Qt provide all of the function to cover the whole winapi?I don't know.If it does,then we should get the application independent from the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `Comdlg32.lib`, not `ComDlg32.dll` which is a dll, not an include library.
Though why not just use [`QPrintDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprintdialog.html)? Also, you need to initialize the `PAGESETUPDLG` variable if you plan on using it, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#setting_up).

> My second question is that do I need to add the #ifdef & #endif statements when I try to call a Windows API function?

You should add them, if you intend on running on a *non-Windows* system, the WinAPI will most certainly not be available (and cause of this you should use [`QMessageBox`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QMessageBox.html)), however, if you system is dependant on WinAPI functions, then there is no point, because you'll be bound to Windows regardless.

Comment: I've changed the lib into LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\ComDlg32.Lib" but gcc still complain about the same error. I've included it <windows.h> header despite console or gui application.Ooops~

Comment: I've given up to use this kind of method. Maybe the path containing the dll file should have no spaces.